# spring security roles issues

Tags: spring, spring-security

I want to have to types os users (admin and user)

This is my security xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/jsp/static/deniedpage.jsp">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/jsp/static/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/jsp/users/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/jsp/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login" logout-url="/logout" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/index" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from Users where USERNAME=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, ur.authority from USERS u, USER_ROLES ur where u.user_id= ur.user_id and u.username=?" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
```

And this is my LoginController

```
@Controller
```

public class LoginController {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String accessUserPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("message",
            "This page is publicly accessible. No authentication is required to view.");
    return "/users/menu";
}

@RequestMapping("/admin/menuAdmin")
public String accessSecuredPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("message",
            "Only you are authenticated and authorized to view this page.");
    return "/admin/menuAdmin";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(ModelMap model) {
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginerror(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("error", "true");
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logout(ModelMap model) {
    return "login";
}
```

Now everytime i'm making the login he goes to that path /jsp/users/menu even if it is the Role_Admin

As you can see i have differents paths

```
<intercept-url pattern="/jsp/static/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
<intercept-url pattern="/jsp/users/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/jsp/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

What's wrong with my code? The login works but not the way i want

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your intercept-URL are wrong.
The pattern should not match the paths to the jsp file , but your URL path. You should write something like this .

```
<intercept-url pattern="/index" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/menuAdmin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
```

Comment: Yes, after sucessful login with admin i'm redirect to the menu from regular user...